# PowerDesigner fails to list Tables in Reverse Enginnering for SAP HANA database schema

Tags: hana, powerdesigner

I try to use PowerDesigner reverse engineering tool to build the diagram of objects under my user's schema.

Although I can connect and see the list of views in "Database Reverse Engineering" dialog, it fails to display the list of tables under target schema.

Any idea how to bring database tables on diagram on SAP PowerDesigner?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Which version of PowerDesigner? How do you connect, JDBC, ODBC?...

Comment: Since in my environment there are different versions of SAP HANA like 1.0 and 2.0, I was confused and tried to connect to a HANA 1.0 database using HANA 2.0 provider. So I realized that the error was because I was using the wrong prover. Thank you pascal, for trying to help me

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: You should put your solution in an answer and accept it - that way it’s easier to see that this in fact is the solution and that the question has been answered. Thanks for sharing anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out that I was using the wrong provider to connect to my HANA database

Though the target HANA database was in HANA 1.0 (since in my environment, I had some other HANA 2.0 systems), I chose provider HANA 2.0 without querying too much

That was the error, when I chose HANA 1.0 data provider, I could successfully see all my schema tables on Power Designer with "Database Reverse Engineering" tool

Thanks to Pascal for leading me to the correct solution